# Missing panel on blender 2.79

Tags: bezier-curves

There is this panel that is on multiple tutorials I have watched which I cant find. [image: pic]

Please help, I am getting really frustrated.

Comment: They might be using a different blender version, have a look in the video which one they -and which one you use. In a daily build from the end of last month in blender 2.9 I have that menu. You can download Daily Builds from https://builder.blender.org/download/

Comment: To clarify is the panel not there with a curve object selected? @WhatAMesh Holy cow, 2.9 already.

Comment: It's the panel that's circled twice and selected.

Comment: Yeah even 2.8 doesn't have the option, and I cant find the 2.9 build you're talking about. Thank you for telling me about the beta though.

Comment: Show a screenshot of *your* project in Blender please. Two possibilitites of lacking that tab so far - either you don't have any curve object selected or you don't have that editor window opened (Properties editor). This is all guess work so far without more info.

Comment: There is no 2.9 yet, just a typo on 2.79 above I assume.  Blender 2.8 has the curve data properties panel.